# Using tooltipster with AJAX data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tooltipster

I'm using the tooltipster plug in, and using AJAX to reload a section of the page.

I have Tasks in a div that are dynamically generated in a list, each task has a 'complete' button next to it, which when clicked loads a tooltip, which works great.

When I then run a function to add a new task, I am taking the div of the task list and reloading it, so the newly made task shows up.

As the whole div reloads, the tooltips attached to all of the tasks then disable and stop working.

Any ideas on how I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Just re-initialize tooltipster on successful reload. Providing both HTML and JS code can help significantly getting your question answered

Comment: I have tried that, but it just comes up with the error message "Tooltipster: one or more tooltips are already attached to the element below. Ignoring."

Comment: This is what you need: http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#delegation

Comment: Can't help much without seeing the code. But it seems like you are doing too much by reloading the entire div. Only append the element that you have updated don't refresh any other element which is not modified.